# FLash Builder Error - 1172: Definition mx.utils.ObjectUtil could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, 2d-games

I am using FB 4.6 with SDK Flex 4.0A. I am trying to import and run an Actionscript (3) Project.

When I build the file, I get the error "1172: Definition mx.utils.ObjectUtil could not be found"

When I look in the Utils folder, there is no ObjectUtil.as file. Is this the problem?

ObjectUtil.as does not seem to be standard in the Util folder. https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/utils/?r=54

Answer (score 0):

If you have pure ActionScript project it's normal that class from Flex SDK could not be found. Try to copy this class from SDK to your project. Also copy classes from list of imports if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectUtil is a [Flex class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html); you'll need to import this project as a Flex project rather than a pure Actionscript project.